# Java image normalization

Tags: java, image-processing, imagej

I am doing the image processing and I am interested in normalization of the image. Somewhere I come to know about the ImageJ library.

So could anyone help me in finding example code for Image normalization using ImageJ library.

Comment: From the menu - Process/Enhance contrast - that should allow you to find the relevant source code. It's either open or GPL'ed (can't recall which).

Comment: It's [_public domain_](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/disclaimer.html).